# Criar tabela dinamica do resultado de um retorno de um exec com variavel Sql server

Tags: sql-server, tabela-banco-de-dados, dinâmico

Bom dia, estou com dificuldade de conseguir fazer  no sql server 2014.

Preciso que o retorno do resultado `exec (@query)` crie uma tabela dinamica com esse resultado preechendo com as colunas e linhas. 
Query que estou usando para montar:

```
DECLARE @COLS VARCHAR(MAX)
        ,@QUERY VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @COLS = STUFF((
    SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME(A.MOTIVO)
    FROM #TMP_GERAR A
        group by A.MOTIVO
    --  ORDER BY A.MOTIVO ASC
        FOR XML PATH('')),1,1, '');

SELECT @COLS

SET @QUERY = 'SELECT * FROM
            (
                SELECT REPRESENTANTE, 
                HORARIO,
                motivo
                FROM #TMP_GERAR 

            ) AS EX
                PIVOT
                (
                    MAX(HORARIO)
                    FOR motivo IN ('+@COLS+')
                )AS X'

-- aqui que gostaria de ter um uma tabela criada 
--dinamicamente para receber o resultado desta variavel 
EXECUTE ( @QUERY)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Objetivo é criar um email HTML com a tabela criada, esse é a unica maneira que conheço até o momento.

Desde já agradeço

Comment: Você diz criar o e-mail e enviar pelo próprio SQL Server? Eu não entendi o que há de dinâmico nessa história

Comment: Ola, isso é um comentario para o meu objetivo apos conseguir criar a tabela dinamica, se for o caso não precisa ler esse objetivo que é apenas uma observação.

Comment: Onde você pretende ler essa tabela?

Comment: ler em uma tabela no email seria isso? nao entendi só queria fazer tipo isso exemplo nem  funciona select into ##tabela from @query, eu só não posso fassa os nomes das colunas pq não sei quais ou quantas viram.

Answer (score 0):

Coloque o comando a seguir dentro da string @QUERY:

```
SELECT * INTO [TABELANOVA] FROM (SEU SELECT)A
```